# SetWindowSize() or WindowHeight and WindowWidth

Tags: c#, console-application

what is the difference between

```
Console.SetWindowSize(20,30);
```

and

```
Console.WindowWidth = 20;
Console.WindowHeight = 30;
```

?

Comment: Probably none, `SetWindowSize()` just breaks it down to a one-liner

Comment: It avoids the flicker you'd get from the window resizing itself twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely nothing except using both of the properties does the operations twice. Here is the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,f907d79481da6ba4):

```
public static int WindowWidth {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Process, ResourceScope.Process)]
    get { 
        Win32Native.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi = GetBufferInfo();
        return csbi.srWindow.Right - csbi.srWindow.Left + 1;
    }
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Process)]
    set {
        SetWindowSize(value, WindowHeight);
    }
}

public static int WindowHeight {
    [System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]  // auto-generated
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Process, ResourceScope.Process)]
    get {
        Win32Native.CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi = GetBufferInfo();
        return csbi.srWindow.Bottom - csbi.srWindow.Top + 1;
    }
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Process)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Process)]
    set {
        SetWindowSize(WindowWidth, value);
    }
}
```

Notice how the two just call `SetWindowSize` with the new value and the current other value (height or width)?

If you really want to get down to gritty details, there is a bit of a difference. Because the properties call `SetWindow` and read the property of the other value, there is some native calls back-and-forth that happen to get that value. So using `SetWindowSize` is more performant than just setting the two properties because it doesn't have to `GetBufferInfo` in the property and create new objects. `GetBufferInfo` is also called by `SetWindowSize` so it avoids an extra call.

Answer (score 4):

The properties actually call the method. So if you choose the second option you call the method twice.

[Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/console.cs,39a174b5cd0f0acd) you can see the source code of the `Console.WindowHeight` property.
In the setter the method is called in combination with the old `Console.WindowWidth` value.